# JSS vue - Error with server.bundle.js after jss deploy package

Tags: jss

Good Morning,

Yesterday I was working on a fresh install of Sitecore 9.1 and followed the documentation for JSS with vue.

Everything was fine. I was able to connect my local app with my Sitecore.

The API Key return a json.

Then I started to add new components and made a deploy package.
In the Content Editor I can see my app, and all components inside.
[image: Imgur]

Nevertheless, in Experience Editor I have this error:

```
Error Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer: window is not defined ReferenceError: window is not defined at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vue.jss\dist\my-app\server.bundle.js:1:396975 at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vue.jss\dist\my-app\server.bundle.js:1:396933 at e.exports (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vue.jss\dist\my-app\server.bundle.js:1:400178) at Object. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vue.jss\dist\my-app\server.bundle.js:1:382155) at __webpack_require__ (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vue.jss\dist\my-app\server.bundle.js:1:236) at Object. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vue.jss\dist\my-app\server.bundle.js:1:107516) at __webpack_require__ (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vue.jss\dist\my-app\server.bundle.js:1:236) at Object. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vue.jss\dist\my-app\server.bundle.js:1:381784) at __webpack_require__ (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vue.jss\dist\my-app\server.bundle.js:1:236) at Object. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vue.jss\dist\my-app\server.bundle.js:1:380876)
   à Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.Http.HttpNodeInstance.d__7`1.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.d__13`1.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.d__10`1.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.d__10`1.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.Helpers.AsyncHelpers.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)
   à Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.PerformRender(TextWriter writer, IRenderEngine renderEngine, String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
   à Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I fixed this error.

1. First, disable UglifyJsPlugin from webpack.shared.js
2. "jss deploy package"
3. Then go to the line specified in the error dist\my-app\server.bundle.js
4. You will find what plugin are causing this error

In my case I needed to change my code in webpack.shared.js like this:

```
    {
      test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: [
          "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
          "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
        ]
      }),
    },
```

Thanks to @Adam  for helping me

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the relevant error is this: `window is not defined`.

This means something in your code (or a 3rd party component) is referencing the `window` object, which is only available when JavaScript is running in the browser. When Node is rendering your JavaScript (server-side rendering), `window` won't be available.

Do you have any first or third-party components that are attempting to use `window`? If it's a component you control, I would suggest adding a conditional statement around your usage of `window`, e.g.

`if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  // it's safe to reference window here
}`

Comment: Thanks Adam, I don't use currently Third-party component, I have just duplicated the Welcome Component from the example.

Then, I created a gulpfile to generate components easily
Then, I changed webpack to generate CSS from SCSS.

I will look again.

Comment: I disabled Uglify and find that "style-loader" made this error, I will find an alternative. Thanks !

Comment: That is strange, as `style-loader` is a webpack-specific dev dependency. Meaning, it shouldn't be in the deployed app bundle.

Comment: It was my mistake when I implemented SCSS. I fixed it like this:

       `{
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: [
              "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
              "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            ]
          }),
        },`