# JSS Vue - getting error in server.bundle on deploy

Tags: jss

This is a similar issue to this one: [JSS vue - Error with server.bundle.js after jss deploy package](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11701/jss-vue-error-with-server-bundle-js-after-jss-deploy-package?rq=1)

But unfortunately I can't comment on that one because my rep is not high enough.  I believe the issue is stemming from at least one of the node modules/Vue plugins I am importing and using on the site.  One is using the window variable quite a few times.  Is there any way to go around this?  I can't control the use of window because it's used in a 3rd party plugin.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I solved this by adding the plugins through a conditional in the main.js file.  Before I was adding directly in the components but this wasn't working.  I'm not sure if this is a permanent solution though.  I may look into adding Nuxt.js to this project to better handle the SSR aspect of Sitecore JSS.

```
import i18ninit from './i18n';
import { createApp } from './createApp';
import './registerServiceWorker';
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueFullPage from 'vue-fullpage.js';
import createjs from 'createjs-module';

i18ninit().then((i18n) => {
  // HTML element to place the app into
  const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

  // retrieve the initial app state if it is defined
  const initialState = window.__JSS_STATE__ || null;

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    // register Vue full page global component
    Vue.use(VueFullPage);
    Vue.prototype.$createjs = createjs;
  }

  const { app } = createApp(initialState, i18n);
  app.$mount(rootElement);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably polyfill `window` as a [Node global](https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/) so that it has something to work against. However, if the library is not designed to support SSR there may be other issues getting it to work.

Comment: I found a node package that might work as a polyfill, do you know where I might include this in the webpack pipeline so that it gets outputted as a global variable?  The way this starter project is setup is somewhat foreign to me.

Comment: You would likely just import the module in the `/server/server.js` entry point, but hard to say without knowing which package you're looking at. Presumably it will add a `window` object to the node `global` object. As Kam mentioned though, you may run into other issues during SSR with this library, depending on what it's expecting to do with `window`.

Comment: Is it as simple as importing something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/window at the top of server.js? `import Window from 'window';
export const window = new Window();`

Comment: Still not having any luck with trying many things.  I feel like something should be built into these sample apps, otherwise it will limit a lot of frontend plugins and prevent people from wanting to use this JSS setup.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with a 3rd party library (Flickity fullscreen) that wasn't checking if `window` is defined. Instead of using `import` I changed it to use `require()`

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  // window is undefined on SSR and fullscreen.js doesn't check for it
  require('flickity-fullscreen/fullscreen.js');
  require('flickity-fullscreen/fullscreen.css');
}
```