# SSR issue: window not defined

Tags: jss

We are using react as client framework for building a SPA. In disconnected mode it works well but then in integrated mode I see the below error when we browse the page or preview it.

Any clue as to what's missing in here?

[image]

Comment: I don't know much about JSS yet, but is everything published? Is this when you browse the page or use the Experience editor? As a guess, it might have something to do with the server side rendering of the react app, is node installed on the server correctly?

Answer (score 9):

The `window` object is not available during server side rendering because Node.js does not have a `window` object 
- it is a browser construct. This is a scenario common to server side rendering (SSR) and JavaScript - it is not specific to JSS.

That said, there are different ways to workaround the problem depending on your app and what is actually trying to use `window`. If it's your code, then try to move any references to `window` into the `componentDidMount` method - that is the appropriate place to interact directly with the DOM in React. Also, `componentDidMount` is not invoked during SSR.

If the code that is referencing `window` is in a 3rd party package/module, then you will want to try to conditionally load that package during rendering. Or conditionally render components from that package when `window` is available, e.g.

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  // it's safe to use window now
}
```

Again, there are several ways to handle this scenario, it largely depends on your situation and application. The primary takeaway is that during SSR you cannot use code that references the browser-specific constructs or objects like `window` or the DOM.

Related questions:

[JSS Vue - getting error in server.bundle on deploy](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/14030/319)

[JSS vue - Error with server.bundle.js after jss deploy package](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/11701/319)

Comment: Just to add to this answer, I ran into this with a 3rd party library (Flickity fullscreen) that wasn't checking if `window` is defined. Instead of using `import` I changed it to use `require()` 

    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      require('flickity-fullscreen/fullscreen.js');
    }